# Log in to remote Linux shell in Python

Tags: python, shell, remote-access

I want to write script on python which could execute shell commands on a remote server.

I find out that I could use something like:

```
# set environment, start new shell
p = Popen("/path/to/env.sh", stdin=PIPE)

# pass commands to the opened shell
p.communicate("python something.py\nexit")
```

But I do not understand how can I login to remote Linux server and execute shell commands there?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173977/remote-server-command-execute

Comment: @pss That one is "without actually logging in". This one is *with* logging in. Although the answer basically says "log in, dude".

Comment: you can use pexpect. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) or [Pyro4](http://pythonhosted.org//Pyro4/) or [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). All of these should do what you would like.